# Iterate through javascript object and add object properties dynamically (key-value pair in JS object)

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I am not sure if this question has been answered earlier. Although i didn't find any relevance to what i wanted. here's the original code.

```
function addrow() {
                  var row = {
                             name: null,
                             city: null,
                             Contact: null,
                             location: null             
                  };

                  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, row, 'first');
}
```

This code adds a new row to the grid table once this function executes by click function. It creates a empty row. The column names are name, city, Contact and location. All these columns entries row gets null value and empty row gets added to the grid.

I want to make this dynamic. i.e. irrespective of the column names and number of columns, it should create empty row for me. for eg. if there are only 2 column names named Name and Age, it should create a row of 2 empty cells.

I tried something like this to make it dynamic.

```
var headers= $line_array.
```

i get the dynamic column header names from an array passed by back-end to front-end. So the column headers are present in an array named headers. Then i added this

```
for(key in row) { headers[key]=null,};
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, row, 'first');
```

So the final addrow() function looks like this

```
function addrow() {

var headers= $line_array;

var i;
var key = headers.length;
var row = {}; // create empty object. we can add header names inside this row for display.

for(key in row) { 
    headers[key]=null,};
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, row, 'first');
}
```

Can someone please suggest me what minor mistake i am committing over here ?

Comment: for(key in row) { headers[key]=null,}; you have an error in your syntax. remove the comma after null.

Comment: Oh no. i missed that. thanks for pointing it out @RichardGrant. works now. :)

Comment: You also misunderstand for loops. ill post that as an answer, its quite long.

Comment: @RichardGrant- the correction allowed me to execute what i wanted. i would like to clear my basics  though.. will wait for your answer. :)

Comment: It should be `for(key in headers) row[key]=null;`

Comment: @RichardGrant- you are right. its far from being solved. It gives me Object {} at the console.log instead of Object {name: null, city: null, Contact: null, Location: null }

Comment: I do not understand JQuery enough to know the proper syntax for this. sorry

Comment: @RichardGrant- Thanks for your inputs. much appreciated.

Comment: @MaxZoom- Tried your way. it still doesnt assign null values to headers to the row object.

Comment: @MaxZoom- My way of assigning in the initial function was Name: null. In the dynamic part, i am assigning it as Name=null. do you think this has to be corrected ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am glad i found the answer myself. Although inputs from @MaxZoon and @RicharGrant helped me understand what might be the issue.

If this code helps anyone, i will be happy. here it is.

```
function addrow() {
    var headers= $line_array;
    var i;
    var key = headers.length;
    var row = {};

    for (i=0; i <headers.length; i++) {
                                       row[headers[i]]=null;
    }

    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, row, 'first');
}
```

This is it. It was as simple as that. I just had to take a look at how a key/value pair is assigned to a Javascript object. Thanks all.